# Tweepy script failing via Github Actions but executes successful locally

Tags: python-3.x, twitter, tweepy, github-actions

I have a Python 3 script that uses the Tweepy library for Twitter that runs fine locally but results in `requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.twitter.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=900)` and `tweepy.error.TweepError: Failed to send request: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.twitter.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=900)` errors when executed from a Github Actions workflow.

Tweepy API instantiation:

```py
tweepy.API(auth, timeout=900, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)
```

The script sends ~1200 requests, so will come up against [Twitter's rate limits](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/rate-limiting). As a result of `wait_on_rate_limit=True` it will wait after the limit is reached. This (coupled with `timeout=900` (upped from the default of `60` to try to debug)) results in it taking ~30 minutes to complete. I can't understand why it doesn't time out locally but does via GitHub Actions.

The script takes ~30 minutes whether it is successful (local) or unsuccessful (Github Actions).